# I want to always display toolbar ios in responsive (safari)

Tags: javascript, css

I'd fixed it ios safari menu always display the status bar menu as picture attached, thanks everyone.
[image]

Comment: Do you want the blue bottom bar always attached?

Comment: yes, i want to bottom always toolbar safari. though scroll up and down it fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `position: fixed` to make something fixed,
and `bottom: 0` with `left: 0` to align something to the bottom left:

```
footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

You can see my code snippet describing it below, or I have a [Codepen](http://codepen.io/The-Quill/pen/pyqvBE) here as well.

```css
footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;

  /* These rules below are just to make the answer look pretty */
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class='main'>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, pri dolor consul commodo ea. <br /> Quo inani rationibus constituam no, sed in ridens civibus. <br /> Vidit detracto corrumpit mel eu, ea iriure integre eum, vim ea possit inciderint. <br /> Eam solum autem et, diam tempor dicunt no nec. <br />

Mea electram persecuti maiestatis at, probo quidam sapientem eu pri. <br /> Ius ut diam nominavi signiferumque, per prima autem maiestatis ex. <br /> Nec ipsum conclusionemque in. <br /> Fabulas recteque ad eos. <br /> Mea et tamquam disputationi, ut has mazim invenire persequeris. <br />

Mei tempor possim consequat at, conceptam expetendis in per, mundi detracto nominati qui no. <br /> Fastidii percipitur ut vim. <br /> Cu accumsan verterem eos, fugit reformidans dissentiunt cu qui. <br /> Ex rebum paulo nam. <br /> Vim ne tantas dissentiet, ea nobis ridens sadipscing pri, an sint atomorum explicari quo. <br /> Mea graeco scripta ei. <br /> Mei mutat reprimique ut. <br />

Ei alii qualisque appellantur ius, dolores sensibus in mel. <br /> Sed expetenda intellegat at, vis ei movet causae tibique, eu vim veniam quodsi. <br /> Est salutatus evertitur eu, te mei iudico melius sanctus. <br /> Ex impedit quaestio mel, senserit convenire elaboraret vix et. <br /> Ei idque postulant maluisset eos, usu graeci oportere te. <br /> Usu error inciderint id, has an integre sententiae, eripuit forensibus ei eam. <br />

Hinc aliquam salutandi mei ea, pro urbanitas necessitatibus an. <br /> Reque labitur splendide eos cu. <br /> Vitae consul vituperata et mei, cum ei summo viris option. <br />  Eu mei quas ceteros, an vix animal admodum accusam, id mollis euismod nec. <br /> Ne sea nibh denique, ut dico erant apeirian sea. <br /> 
</div>
<footer>
  I'm a footer!
</footer>
```